# Maximum square that can be incribed in a right angle with one vertex on the hypotenuse

Tags: geometry

A right angled triangle has the sides 3cm, 4 cm and 5 cm. find out the area of the greatest square that can be inscribed in it with one of the vertices of the square on the hypotenuse??

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck? what area of geometry are you currently studying? this information will help form an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the left triangle
$$
s=\frac3{\frac54+\frac35}=\frac{60}{37}
$$
In the right triangle
$$
s=\frac3{\frac34+1}=\frac{12}7
$$